# C# progressBar not updating until half progress complete

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, progress-bar, dispatchertimer

I am using a `dispatcherTimer` to update the progressBar's Value:

```
DispatcherTimer tim = new DispatcherTimer();
tim.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
tim.Tick += delegate
{
    if (valuee < max)
    {
        prog.Value = valuee;
    }
    else
    {
        tim.Stop();
    }
};
```

And setting the progressBar's maximum value like this:

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(Filename, FileMode.Open))
{
    if (fs.Length > 10485760 && fs.Length <= 209715200)
        prog.Maximum = fs.Length / 1024;
    else if (fs.Length <= 10485760)
        prog.Maximum = fs.Length / 16;
    else if(fs.Length > 209715200)
        prog.Maximum = fs.Length / 1048576;
}
```

Then increasing the value after every iteration of the for loop:

```
var Input = File.OpenRead(path);
int Size = MainWindow.prog.Maximum;
for (long i = 0; i < Input.Length; i += Size)
{
    MainWindow.valuee++;
    PasswordEnter.valuee++;
    byte[] chunkData = new byte[chunkSize];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    while ((bytesRead = fsInput.Read(chunkData, 0, chunkSize)) > 0)
    {
        if (bytesRead != chunkSize)
        {
            for (int x = bytesRead - 1; x < chunkSize; x++)
            {
                chunkData[x] = 0;
            }
        }
        cryptoStream.Write(chunkData, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: This is how I am calling the AESCryptography class:

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.DoWork += (obj, l) => lo.Encrypt(Filename, password.Password, "main");
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

But for some reason the progressBar doesn't update until more than half the iterations are over! what's wrong?

Comment: What code is running on which thread(s)? What else happens in the `for` loop?

Comment: block #3 is on the other thread

Comment: Is there a reason that you've avoided using the `ReportProgress`/`ProgressChanged` mechanism on the `BackgroundWorker` thread? It's worked well for me updating progress bars and status displays. Your looping code opens a file, then inside the `for` loop increments the progress (`valuee`). It appears that the `while` loop reads to end-of-file. The `for` loop then keeps having the `while` make sure that it is still at EOF since no new file is opened. (I'm assuming that `Input` and `fsInput` are supposed to be the same variable.)

Comment: @HABO post your comment as an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your looping code opens a file, then inside the `for` loop increments the progress (`valuee`). It appears that the `while` loop reads to end-of-file. The `for` loop then keeps having the `while` make sure that it is still at EOF since no new file is opened. (I'm assuming that `Input` and `fsInput` are supposed to be the same variable.)

The `ReportProgress`/`ProgressChanged` mechanism on the `BackgroundWorker` thread is a reliable way to handle the cross-thread intricacies of updating the UI from a background worker thread. You can use [`UserState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.progresschangedeventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to pass additional information, e.g. the name of the file currently being processed to display in a label.

Answer (score 2):

A [`DispatcherTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer(v=vs.110).aspx) queues work on the `Dispatcher` thread, which is WPF UI thread.

This is what MSDN says regarding the execution of the timer:

> The DispatcherTimer is reevaluated at the top of every Dispatcher loop.
>   **Timers are not guaranteed to execute exactly when the time interval occurs**, but they are guaranteed to not execute before the time interval occurs. This is because DispatcherTimer operations are placed on the Dispatcher queue like other operations. When the DispatcherTimer operation executes is dependent on the other jobs in the queue and their priorities.

You're experiencing the lag in the progress timer because you are *most likely* running a long blocking operation which denies the messageloop of processing different requests.

You have two options:

1. Move the long running operation to a background thread. I would prefer this approach.
2. Try using the [`DispatcherTimer` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615008(v=vs.110).aspx) which takes a [`DispatcherPriority`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority(v=vs.110).aspx) and specifying a higher priority. This approach still does not guarantee you'll experience change in performance, but it may help.

Comment: Can you add its code? I want to see how you call it

Comment: Done. not properly formatted yet but I still posted it

Comment: I want to see *the call* to the background thread, not the delegate running inside

Comment: It seems fine. Are there any other things going on in your UI thread?

Comment: I just noticed: valuee is updated **once**, has a long wait then starts working properly. but the rest of the code in the for loop doesn't stop once!

Comment: `MainWindow.valuee++;` the variable that stores the progressBar's value

Comment: *"valuee is updated once, has a long wait"* What piece of code executes after that first assignment?

Comment: nothing. I've been looking for something for days! :P

Comment: logically nothing on the UI thread can be a problem because the ProgressBar updates fine! it's valuee that doesn't increase!

Comment: If `valuee` doesn't increase, how is the `ProgressBar` progressing?

Comment: valuee increases but after an awkward wait!

Comment: What i mean is it bound to any `Control`. I dont think we're seeing enough code to see why it's hanging

Comment: no it isn't bound to anything, it's first initialized: `public static int valuee = 0;` and then used where you saw it